# Trying to update image control source from other tread and getting Error

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

My project is about capturing the full screen and updating the image control by this images;

At the last line (`image1.Source = img;`) I get the error:

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    delegate void  MyDel(BitmapImage img);

    Queue<BitmapImage> picQueue = new Queue<BitmapImage>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Thread updateTrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateQueue));
        updateTrd.Start();

        Thread PicTrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateScreen));
        PicTrd.Start();
    }

    private void UpdateQueue()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();//this function provide a desktop screenshot
            System.Drawing.Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.StreamSource = stream;
            image.EndInit();

            picQueue.Enqueue(image);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateScreen()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (picQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                SwitchPic(picQueue.Dequeue());
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
        }
    }

    private void SwitchPic(BitmapImage img)
    {
        if(!image1.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            this.image1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new MyDel(SwitchPic), img);
        }
        else
        {
            image1.Source = img;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### The solution

The image passed into `SwitchPic` is owned by another thread. Simply change the line `if(!image1.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())` to `if(!img.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())`.

```
private void SwitchPic(BitmapImage img)
{
    if(!img.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        this.image1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new MyDel(SwitchPic), img);
    }
    else
    {
        image1.Source = img;
    }
}
```

---

### How to improve

Let's start with getting those while loops out of the way, since they'll eat your CPU.

- Instead of wrapping a while loop around your `UpdateQueue` method,
  then create a `Timer`.
- Instead of using a `Queue<T>`, then use a `BlockingCollection<T>`
  which is made for concurrent access - this way you eliminate the
  second infinity while loop.

The above is actually the recipe of a [producer/consumer pattern](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/3023):

- The thread used by the `Timer` is our *producer*, since it *adds*
  items to the collection.
- The thread that invokes `UpdateScreen` is our *consumer*, since it
  *removes* items from the collection.

Your code example already uses this pattern (kinda), however it's not able to block the thread when no items are in the collection. Instead you're doing `Thread.Sleep(30)` which haves a huge perfomance overhead, compared to simply blocking the thread with `Take` method from `BlockingCollection<T>`.

Further more, we can simply remove the `SwitchPic` method, and merge it into `UpdateScreen`, since it makes no real sense to have this as a seperate method - it's only invoked from the `UpdateScreen` method.

We don't have to check for `CheckAccess` anymore on the image, because the image is always created by the thread the `Timer` uses (The thread the `Timer` uses is a special thread, and can therefore not be used by anyone else). Also that the `UpdateScreen` runs on a dedicated thread, eliminates the need for the `CheckAccess`.

As I assume that you want the images to display in order, I'm using `Dispatcher.Invoke` and not `Dispathcer.BeginInvoke`.

The code then looks like:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private BlockingCollection<BitmapImage> pictures = new BlockingCollection<BitmapImage>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var takeScreen = new Timer(o => TakeScreenshot(), null, 0, 10);
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateScreen)).Start();
        }

        private void TakeScreenshot()
        {
            var sc = new ScreenCapture();
            var img = sc.CaptureScreen();

            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.StreamSource = stream;
            image.EndInit();

            pictures.Add(image);
        }

        private void UpdateScreen()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var item = pictures.Take(); // blocks if count == 0
                item.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => image1.Source = item));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i got error : Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type at this line:item.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => image1.Source = item);

Comment: @OzShimon, My bad - updated the code. Was targeting .NET 4.5 while making up the code.

Comment: the code is working but now i got: NullReferenceException from some reason. i posted other post about it: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205129/trying-to-update-control-and-getting-nullreferenceexception  plase help me :)thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since your `picQueue is created on main thread` so queue and dequeue operation throwing an error. Put this operation on dipatcher for main thread to reslove the `thread affinity`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Dispatcher Property within Window. The Invoke method helps to swap you code to the GUI thread. Something like:

```
Dispather.Invoke(()=>{ YourCodeinMainTreadHere();})
```

Comment: I think SwitchPic should look like: Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{image1.Source = img;})

Answer (score 0):

You could create a global variable theBitmap, and then instead of setting the image1.Source = img; in the same line set theBitmap = img; Then use a timer such that

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         image1.source = theBitmap
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a thread then I will suggest you to use a static resource (Object Data Provider) to update values in another thread.

Because Static Resources are available to all threads, and you can change their values from any thread. And bind an image property of an image to this static resource. When a static resource gets updated it will update the image too. I have used this way to update a progress bar value, so I think it will work here too.