# Trying to update control and getting NullReferenceException

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, nullreferenceexception

i got answer to my last problem related to my mini project: when i tried to update image control from other thread i got error:
[Trying to update image control source from other tread and getting Error- enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201276/trying-to-update-image-control-source-from-other-tread-and-getting-error)

but now i got **NullReferenceException** at this line:

```
item.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => image1.Source = item));
```

from some reason and i dont know why?

the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    BlockingCollection<BitmapSource> pictures = new BlockingCollection<BitmapSource>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
        System.Drawing.Image source = sc.CaptureScreen();
        System.Windows.Media.ImageSource img = ToWpfBitmap(source);
        this.image1.Source = img; 
    }

    public BitmapSource ToWpfBitmap(System.Drawing.Image bitmap)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

            stream.Position = 0;
            BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
            result.BeginInit();
            result.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            result.StreamSource = stream;
            result.EndInit();
            result.Freeze();
            return result;
        }
    }

    private void TakeScreenshot()
    {
        while (true)
        {        
            ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
            System.Drawing.Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
            pictures.Add(ToWpfBitmap(img));           
        }   
    }

    private void UpdateScreen()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (pictures.Count > 10)
            {
                var item = pictures.Take(); // blocks if count == 0
                item.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => image1.Source = item));
            }
        }
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var takeScreen = new Timer(o => TakeScreenshot(), null, 0, 10);
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(TakeScreenshot)).Start();
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateScreen)).Start();
    }
}
```

thanks for every one :)

Comment: Did you even read my answer for your other question, or did you simply copy+paste the code? - Why are you starting both a `Timer`, and a dedicated thread, which both invokes the `TakeScreenshot` method?

Comment: your code is pass rebuild but all i see whem i run the program is white window.

Comment: can you try use this Cupture class to check it? [Link]http://pastebin.com/E9HDpVyr

Comment: i added new thread just to check something / try your code with CuptureScreen class and see the notting happend

Answer (score 0):

I believe returning value before Using(...) statement finishes doesn't dispose disposable, and can cause problems too, i am not sure how it reflects this thought.